# how to trim n characters of string in python?

Tags: python, string, strip

I'm new to python. I would like to trim a string **only if it's last 6 digits are zeros**. 
I checked the **strip()** methods, but I don't see one that indicates the **n number** of characters to trim from right.

sample string:

```
20121124000000
```

result string should be:

```
20121124
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = s[:-6] if s.endswith('000000') else s
```

or define a function:

```
def rstrip_chars(s, chars):
    return s[:-len(chars)] if s.endswith(chars) else s

s = rstrip_chars(s, '000000')
```